# Responsive table formatting

Tags: css, responsive-design, html-table

I have the table below which allows a user (via jQuery UI slider - represented as SL1, etc...) to adjust a % of sun hours for the month. I want the table yo become responsive such that I end up with 3 rows of four months when viewing it by the phone. How to break the responsiveness at col 5, col 9?

PC Browser:

```
jan  feb  mar  apr  may  jun  jul  aug...
50%  75%  78%  80%  74%  72%  70%  65%
SL1  SL2  SL3  SL4  SL5  SL6  SL7  SL8
```

On Phone:

```
jan  feb  mar  apr  
50%  75%  78%  80%  
SL1  SL2  SL3  SL4

may  jun  jul  aug...
74%  72%  70%  65%
SL5  SL6  SL7  SL8
```

My current HTML is:

```
<table id="sun-season">
  <thead>
  <tr>
     <th><label for="amount-jan">Jan</label></th>
     <th><label for="amount-feb">Feb</label></th>
     <th><label for="amount-mar">Mar</label></th>
     <th><label for="amount-apr">Apr</label></th>
     <th><label for="amount-may">May</label></th>
     <th><label for="amount-jun">Jun</label></th>
     <th><label for="amount-jul">Jul</label></th>
     <th><label for="amount-aug">Aug</label></th>
     <th><label for="amount-sep">Sep</label></th>
     <th><label for="amount-oct">Oct</label></th>
     <th><label for="amount-nov">Nov</label></th>
     <th><label for="amount-dec">Dec</label></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td><input type="text" id="amount-jan" readonly class="mthy-mix"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="amount-feb" readonly class="mthy-mix"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="amount-mar" readonly class="mthy-mix"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="amount-apr" readonly class="mthy-mix"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="amount-may" readonly class="mthy-mix"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="amount-jun" readonly class="mthy-mix"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="amount-jul" readonly class="mthy-mix"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="amount-aug" readonly class="mthy-mix"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="amount-sep" readonly class="mthy-mix"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="amount-oct" readonly class="mthy-mix"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="amount-nov" readonly class="mthy-mix"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="amount-dev" readonly class="mthy-mix"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><div id="slider-jan"></div></td>
     <td><div id="slider-feb"></div></td>
     <td><div id="slider-mar"></div></td>
     <td><div id="slider-apr"></div></td>
     <td><div id="slider-may"></div></td>
     <td><div id="slider-jun"></div></td>
     <td><div id="slider-jul"></div></td>
     <td><div id="slider-aug"></div></td>
     <td><div id="slider-sep"></div></td>
     <td><div id="slider-oct"></div></td>
     <td><div id="slider-nov"></div></td>
     <td><div id="slider-dec"></div></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are welling to keep all rows on mobile (not breaking them less), FooTables is a great solution, I'm personally using it:

http://css-tricks.com/footable-a-jquery-plugin-for-responsive-data-tables/

Many options are available through this jQuery plugin, it is up to you how to use it.

Comment: Hi Antoine, thanks for the link. I will look into how it can do the above.